# Glob for NUnit dlls

Tags: powershell, nunit, glob

We have the following command which SHOULD search for all dlls of test:

> packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe --result=${env:CI_PROJECT_DIR}\sonite.tests.xml`;transform=nunit3-junit.xslt --noheader --agents=5 --workers=5 --trace=Off ((ls -Recurse ***Test(s).dll** | % FullName) -Match "\bin\")

In the pipeline we get the following error:

> The term 's' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

I was expecting this to work where **s** is optional. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I'm running it from a powershell command.

Comment: Now I get the following error:

+ ... der --agents=5 --workers=5 --trace=Off ((ls -Recurse *Test{,s}.dll |  ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token 's' in expression or statement.

Comment: I tagged it wrongly above. It's a powershell. command.

Comment: Try `(ls -Recurse *Test*.dll | ? { $_.Name -match 'Tests?\.dll$' } | % FullName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all files with `Test` string in them, and end with `.dll` extension, and then check if the strings ends with `Test.dll` or `Tests.dll` using a regex:

```
(ls -Recurse *Test*.dll | ? { $_.Name -match 'Tests?\.dll$' } | % FullName)
```

*Details*:

- `Test` - `Test`
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `\.dll` - `.dll`
- `$` - end of string.

Note `-match` is case insensitive, if you need it to be case sensitive, use `-cmatch`.